# How to find max INT value of a table relative to the row

Tags: mysql

let's say I have this table: a

```
keys   speed
a     4
b     10
c     5
```

I wish to find the row with the highest speed relative to keys

E.g This is desired

```
keys  speed
b     10
```

MY ATTEMPT

```
SELECT
    keys, max(speed)
FROM a
```

This give gives me the highest speed but wrong key

```
keys   max(speed)
a      10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a subquery to find the max speed first.

```
  SELECT *
  FROM A
  WHERE A.speed = (SELECT MAX(A1.speed) FROM A as A1)
```

Be aware if multiple rows share the max speed, all matching rows will be return.